# Make a call to a specific number when app starts

Tags: xcode

I want to make an app (iOS12 or above). When it opens it prompt to call a number (with cancel or call option). It will be one fixed number. After I tap on "call" or "cancel" , I want the App to be close.

I am new to XCode. just started learning

Comment: Please always ask spesific question to programming issues. You are very unspesific. Try it first by yourself and later you can ask if you have a problem in your code.

Comment: Then you need to continue learning, you can’t come here and request us to write an app for you. You start writing it and then you come back when you have a specific issue with your code that you need help with

Answer (score 1):

Placing a call is just a matter of opening a `tel:` URL:

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL("tel:...")!)
```

If you want to do that on launch, that's in `UIApplicationDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching`.

Note that this kind of app would almost certainly be rejected by the App Store for doing too little, but it's certainly writable.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code to open the phone number on the **Phone app**:

```
if let phoneURL = URL("tel:1234567890") {
  UIApplication.shared.open(phoneURL)
}
```

The thing is that you also asks that the app should be closed. This is something Apple doesn't like for apps to do. If you need to call somebody, do that, and then you should go back to the app that needed to make a call. So the app can't get closed after open the Phone app.